# CasperJS crashes - can they be avoided with refresh or reinstance?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

hope you're having an awesome day.

I'm running a CasperJS scrape across around 100,000 links over the course of a few days (continuously).

For every 500 or so, casperJS crashes randomly. When reloaded and started from the last link, however, it continues for another 500.

I was wondering if someone knows of an effective way I might be able to refresh or close & reinstance casperjs, to avoid this burnout? I was thinking of an exit() paired with a wait, but very keen on thoughts!

The script is similar to:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: true,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'
  },
  clientScripts: ['vendor/jquery.min.js', 'vendor/lodash.js'],
 viewportSize: {
    width: 1600,
    height:1000
  }
});

var linkArray = [ // Includes 100,000 + links ]

function inspectUrl(url) {
    casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
        title = this.getPageTitle();
        bodyText = this.fetchText('body');

        // Includes a bunch of other tasks to do.
}


casper.start('https://www.google.com.au', function() {
    console.log('Booting up CasperJS...');
});

casper.then(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
        inspectUrl(linkArray[i]);
    };
});

casper.run()
```

Comment: is there any type of error/debug/logging information you have available when it crashes? you may be better off just finding the root of the problem

Comment: Negative, phantomjs just crashes. I console.log every resource header so that, if it is a specific request causing the hang, I would be able to work on that. Instead, it just seems to be a memory churn issue .

Comment: I found an option, but never test it by myself on github:  https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/pull/826#issuecomment-34950562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known PhantomJS memory problem. You should develop a "runner", which runs your CasperJS script with some 400 links, collects result, then runs another instance of the script with another portion of links and so far.

Maybe you can make some CasperJS instances run in parallel, if you need speed.

You can develop such a runner with PhantomJS, using the **spawn** function.
The function is described briefly in the PhantomJS docs: http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/

**UPDATE:**

You can find below a working example of such a runner. The example is very simple, just to demonstrate how one could **spawn** CasperJS instances and collect their results. In particular, there is no error handling in the example at all. The example have been tested with PhantomJS 2.1.1.

The runner uses Q promises, so first you have to make file **package.json** with the following content:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "q": "1.4.1"
    }
}
```

and run installer:

> npm install

Then you have to create **runner.js**:

```
var Q = require('q');
var childProcess = require('child_process');

var parserTasks = [
    'http://phantomjs.org/',
    'http://casperjs.org/',
    'https://jquery.com/'
];

run(parserTasks).then(function(result) {
    console.log('Tasks result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
    phantom.exit();
});

function run(tasks) {
    if (tasks.length) {
        var task = tasks.pop();
        return runTask(task).then(function(result) {
            console.log('result: ' + result);
            return run(tasks).then(function(results) {
                return([result].concat(results));
            });
        });
    } else {
        return Q([]);
    }
}

function runTask(task) {
    var defer = Q.defer();

    var spawn = childProcess.spawn;
    var result = '';
    var child = spawn('casperjs', ['parser.js', task]);
    console.log("spawn run: " + task);
    child.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
        result += data;
    });
    child.on("exit", function() {
        defer.resolve(result);
    });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

and **parser.js**

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var url = casper.cli.args[0];

var result;

casper.start();

casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    result = this.getTitle();
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(result).exit();
});
```

You could execute the runner the following way, meaning that **phantomjs** executable is somewhere on PATH.

> phantomjs runner.js

The output should be the following:

```
spawn run: https://jquery.com/
result: jQuery

spawn run: http://casperjs.org/
result: CasperJS, a navigation scripting and testing utility for PhantomJS and SlimerJS

spawn run: http://phantomjs.org/
result: PhantomJS | PhantomJS

Tasks result: ["jQuery\n","CasperJS, a navigation scripting and testing utility for PhantomJS and SlimerJS\n","PhantomJS | PhantomJS\n"]
```

Comment: Would love to hear more about this if you have any info/examples - sounds like something I definitely have to do, would really appreciate any info you have :)

Comment: Hey there @a-bobkov, would I be able to chat with you directly about how I might set this up? :)

Comment: I'll try to make an example for you, possibly on the weekend :-)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much!

Comment: @jakequade I added an example, as I promised. Hope this helps!